# Use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(x)$ for $f(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$. I don't even know where to start with this. I have done $\sqrt{x-2}= (x-2)^.5$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Note: The step $\sqrt{x-2}=(x-2)^{0.5}$ is correct, but not helpful, in this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate a derivative of $f(x)$ using "the definition" you must find:

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Begin by writing the above down, but with your function in for $f(x)$ throughout.

In this problem, there's a further trick you will need, namely that $$(\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b})(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b})=a-b$$
Hence, you multiply numerator and denominator by the conjugate of the numerator, which in this case will be $(\sqrt{x+h-2}+\sqrt{x-2})$.  Then, simplify, and you will no longer have $\frac{0}{0}$ in the limit.

Comment: Is this the answer "1/(2(x-2)^(.5) )

Comment: yes, that's the answer.  You can check with alpha, or with differentiation rules.